# Converting list to python array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list as follows:

```
domain_names = [{'fqdn': '*.google.com', 'port': '443', 'protocol': 'tcp'}, {'fqdn': '*.github.com', 'port': '443', 'protocol': 'tcp'}, {'fqdn': '*.amazonaws.com', 'port': '443', 'protocol': 'tcp'}, {'fqdn': '*.aviatrix.com', 'port': '443', 'protocol': 'tcp'}]
```

I need to convert it to an array as the API needs an array for the data to be passed. I have tried Numpy.array(domain_names) which return numpy.ndarray which is also not allowed to pass. The API strictly allows array.
I tried the following:
arr = [] # This is an array
    for d in domain_names:
        arr.append(d)
    print(type(arr)) # this is a list

Can anyone suggest me a way to convert it to an array?
Thanks in advance!

```
def set_new_filter_tag(url= None, CID=None, tag_name=None,domain_names=None):
    arr = []
    for d in domain_names:
        arr.append(d)
    print(arr)
    data = {
        "action":"set_fqdn_filter_tag_domain_names",
        "CID": CID,
        "tag_name": tag_name,
        "domain_names": arr
    }
    response = requests.post(url=url, data=data, verify=False)
    res_dict = response.json()
    if res_dict["return"]:
           print(res_dict)
    else:
            print(res_dict)
            print("ERROR: setting new tag is failed.")
```

The error is 
`{'return': False, 'reason': 'domain_names should be an array.'}`

Comment: What API?  Javascript array is very much like Python list.

Comment: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/avx-apidoc/index.htm
Check section 288 set_fqdn_filter_tag_domain_names

Comment: You probably want to make into json.  But...  Really need to see some code here...

Comment: Please edit that into your question

Comment: That API refers to *json arrays* which correspond to Python `list` objects.

Comment: and what exactly is the error you get back?

Comment: @HariMenon {'return': False, 'reason': 'domain_names should be an array.'}

Comment: @Anoop, put that into the question.....

Comment: @StephenRauch I have edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: You need to provide the data as `json=data` I believe, or manually serialize if you use the data parameter, `data=json.dumps(data)` otherwise it is form encoded, I believe

Comment: @Anoop, I do not see the returned error in the question.  If someone in comments wants more information.  Put the information into the question.  In general, it is expected that the question will have most or all of the information that is being asked for here, in the question, when you first post it.

Comment: @StephenRauch Sorry updated again. Thanks for the info